Installation of ubuntu 22.04 for Jetson Agx Orin
I recently bought Jetson Agx Orin and our environment needs installation of ubuntu 22.04 on Jetson. But I have some problems.

I have a problem with making usb memory for ubuntu 22.04 image.
I downloaded ubuntu image on https://ubuntu.com/download/nvidia-jetson and also unzipped. But, I couldn't connect to UEFI boot mode and my usb didn't working. I'm also wondering what format I should set for USB.

I downloaded bootsystem but I can not understand this program.
(sudo ./flash.sh p3737-0000-p3701-0000-qspi internal) I used this command and tried to reboot but, there was an error for there isn't file or device for this command.


Please let me know how to solve this problems and install ubuntu 22.04 for Jetson AGX Orin. I'll be waiting for your answers.

What do you mean by USB is broken? Do you mean you need to buy a new USB drive or are you saying that on the computer there is not a single working USB port? Please edit the question and clarify.

I mean that my USB do not working. I already read the instruction for installing ubuntu 22.04 for jetson agx orin and followed all. But I can't understand well. I'll really appreciated if you help me.
